# Explain units for negative exponent

Tags: unit-of-measure

From a textbook of recent publication;

"The average radiation on the Earth’s surface is $340 W m^{−2}$."

I get the 340W.  I presume m is meters. How does a minus 2 affect a meter, rather a square meter?

Comment: Format error. The -2 is an exponent of  m.  Quote should be trailing quote paired with the first one.

Comment: Why the tag is [negative-binomial]?

Answer (score 1):

It should be read as "per" and without the negative. So, in your case, "watts per square meter."  You do the same thing with "miles per hour," which is 
$$
\frac{\text{miles}}{\text{hour}} = \text{miles} \cdot \text{hour}^{-1}
$$

Comment: So is the negative sign a typo?

Comment: NO, that's what it means.  Multiplication by negative exponents means dividing by the same power (without the minus sign).

Comment: What is the difference between m**2  and m**-2 ?

Comment: I own 2 square meters of property, and it cost me \$5 PER square meter.  The first has units $m^2$ (how much I own) and the second $\frac{\text{dollars}}{m^2} = \text{dollars}\cdot m^{-2}$ (the rate at which I paid for it).